# Is it possible to proxy the html get request to /graphql from a create-react-app?

Tags: proxy, create-react-app

I have a create-react-app application in which I enabled the proxy by adding:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
```

to my package.json. That's working well for API requests to /graphql, but when the web browser request /graphql (for the purpose of loading the UI to run queries) gets handled by the frontend and not proxied. Is it possible to also proxy it?

Same thing happens when I try to do OAuth by visiting https://localhost:3000/auth/facebook, the frontend handles it instead of the backend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed possible to further customize the proxy.

First, when a web browser requests `/graphql` or `/auth/facebook`, it sends an `Accept` header that holds `text/html` (among others). The configuration of the CRA proxy [specifically *ignores*](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development) requests with this header value:

> The development server will **only** attempt to send requests without text/html in its Accept header to the proxy.

(emphasis in original text)

Luckily, you may override the default configuration and basically hook the proxy middleware to your liking. [There are detailed instructions in the docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually) and even more so in the [npm package docs](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#example), but the crux of it is:

```
  app.use(
    '/graphql',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:3001',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
```

Comment: thanks alot. I also had to change `return fetch("/api/graphql", { [...] }` to `return fetch("/graphql", { [...] }` but that probably depends on my backend config